# Removing parts of a quote pulled from an API python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a discord bot and I decided to make a quote command, I'm using this quote API: https://github.com/lukePeavey/quotable - and this is the link that the bot accesses: https://api.quotable.io/random.

the bot successfully sends a quote, here's an example of what it sent:

`{'_id': 'O_jlFdjUtHPT', 'tags': ['famous-quotes'], 'content': 'Every person, all the events of your life are there because you have drawn them there. What you choose to do with them is up to you.', 'author': 'Richard Bach', 'length': 132}`

the problem is, I can't figure out how I would make it so it just includes the quote and the author.

this is the code I have that sends what's above.

```
    @commands.command()
    async def quote(self, ctx):
        """fetches a random quote."""
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get('https://api.quotable.io/random') as q:
                if q.status == 200:
                    js = await q.json()
                    await ctx.send(js)
```

I tried changing it to:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def quote(self, ctx):
        """fetches a random quote."""
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get('https://api.quotable.io/random') as q:
                if q.status == 200:
                    js = await q.json()
                    await ctx.send(f'> {js.content}\n- {js.author}')
```

but that just returns the error:

```
gnoring exception in command quote:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Goldilocks/Desktop/CodeStuff/b1nzyBotRepo/cogs/bettersimple.py", line 108, in quote
    await ctx.send(f'{js.content}\n-{js.author}')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'content'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'content'
```

what am I doing wrong here and what should I be changing to fix it?

Comment: js will be a dictionary and not an object with `content` and `author` as attributes.

Comment: python is not like javascript, to access a key in a dict you need to use strings in brackets, e.g `my_dict["my_key"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the error, `q` is a dictionary. A value is retrieved from a dictionary by specifying its corresponding key in square brackets, not with a dot. so, to get the quote's content, you would have to do this: `q['content']`, not `q.content`. so this would be the ideal code:

```py
@commands.command()
    async def quote(self, ctx):
        """fetches a random quote."""
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get('https://api.quotable.io/random') as q:
                if q['status'] == 200:
                    js = await q.json()
                    await ctx.send(f'> {js['content']}\n- {js['author']}')
```

Comment: Same as in the answer from **IPSDSILVA**, `q` is a `ClientResponse` instance, you can't do `js = json.loads(q)`, to get the json response: `js = await q.json()`

Answer (score 2):

If I am correctly understanding what you are trying to get at, you are getting the JSON data from the link, and then taking the author and content from it. Your code should look a little like this:

```py
@commands.command()
async def quote(self, ctx):
"""fetches a random quote."""
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get('https://api.quotable.io/random') as quote_json:
        q = quote_json.json()  # Make sure to import json
    if q['status'] == 200:
        await ctx.send(f'{q["content"]}\n~ {q["author"]}')
    else:
        await ctx.send('An error occurred')
```

What the code above does is that it gets the information from the website API, but when it's returned, it will be returned as a string, not a JSON object. We then use `q = json.loads(quote_json)`. Make sure you `import json` at the top. After that, we get the status, and if it's `200`, which is what we want, we continue with the code. Otherwise, there is an error message that is sent. If the code is `200` we get the `content` and `author` from the JSON object, and we send that ordered in the following form:

```
This is the amazing quote received from the API.
~ IPSDSILVA#1849
```

Comment: `quote_json` is a `ClientResponse` instance, you can't do `q = json.loads(quote_json)`, to get the json response: `q = await quote_json.json()`